# Create a New Page During Text to PDF conversion Using Itext

Tags: java, itext

I am converting a text file to PDF using iText. The conversion works fine but I need that during conversion if the BufferedReader encounters a certain text, a new PDF Page is Started. This is what I have tried But A new Page is not started when that Text is encountered. My Sample code is as Below(Just the relevant part).

```
Document output = new Document(PageSize.B3);
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:/ABC Statements final/File.TXT");
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Pdf Statements/File.PDF"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(output, file);
                output.open();
                writer.open();
.............................
String pageend = "Page Total";
                String trimmedend = br.readLine().trim();
                if (trimmedend.startsWith(pageend)) {
                    output.newPage();
                }
```

Comment: output.newPage() is the correct method to start a newPage(), although it will be ignored if the current page doesn't have any content. What happens if you add a System.out to the if statement. Is output.newPage() ever called? If not, you've found your problem, and it's not iText related.

Comment: You are right Sir, My `System.out.println(trimmedend);` does not print out anything , I will recheck My code.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. It is redundant and confusing. Please remove it from your example as this bad code gets copied a lot.

Comment: OK Removed it from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to change your `if`-statement to something like this:

```
String pageend = "page total";
...
if (trimmedend.toLowerCase().contains(pageend)) {
    ...
}
```

This way, you avoid case-sensitivity and you avoid the problem of having characters that aren't considered being white space before "page total". Of course: this is just an educated guess. I don't know what your original data stream looks like.